# JSF and Javascript and HTML - How to create a highly dynamic interface

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I'm new to JSF and developing web applications with Java. 
I'm basically developing a pretty complex interface, with lots of AJAX content loaded (Pagination, posts, comments, ...).

I'll start with a basic example, a user writes a comment. The form is sent through JSF f:ajax to the server and then I can do a render="sectionId", but the problem is, that I want to make the post not just appear, but slide down and even toggle background color.

How can I obtain this sort of effect using JSF and Javascript?
The designer (who knows only HTML/CSS/Javscript/Jquery) says that usually, he just does a Jquery AJAX call to a page with a string of data and then the page generates a JSON encode that he can then use to do all the magic.

I'm not asking how you do the toggle/color in jquery, it's the communication between the JSF and Javascript. So how can I send to his javascript the newly generated HTML code, so that he can what he wants with it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Remember that JSF components generate plain HTML. You `<h:commandButton>`s will become `<input type="submit />`, `<h:panelGrid>` will become `<table>` and so on, so you can use jQuery as long as you know how the HTML will be generated for your page(s).

Comment: Thanks. How can the javascript catch the newly generated HTML? Once the designer can catch it, he will be able to put it where he wants, the way he wants...

Comment: [Here](http://exadel.com/web/portal/jsftags-guide) is a good start point for your needs.

Comment: Thanks again. But we do not have a problem understanding the JSF tags. The problem is when JSF does an AJAX event and generates new HTML (such as the post display in my example), instead of using the render, we would like the HTML to be given to our custom javascript so that he can do the funky effects.

Comment: There is the `onevent` tag attribute in the `<f:ajax>` that receives a javascript method. You can handle the ajax status in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF is a server-side technology and you'd typically conditionally display content within
a construct such as a panelGroup, so why not include your jquery magic inside a ready
handler inside the conditionally rendered panelGroup like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="ajaxRenderTarget">
  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.listOfComments}" var="var">
  ... display required information ...
  </ui:repeat>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.showJqueryEffects}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            ... funky effects here ...
        });
    </script>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Where I've used ui:repeat in the above example you could be and probably would be using any data iteration component from jsf or a component library such as a datatable.

Another thing to consider is [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript) which has `<o:onloadScript>` and a host of other tags which are worth knowing about.

One mistake to avoid is trying to load JSF pages using jQuery ajax functions, the server will have no state of the component tree and it won't work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Using the simple example, that would mean that the I would be default do display:none for the comment, and then when it reads the script, do the slideDown and toggleColor... right?

Comment: Not quite - when the EL expression evaluates to rendered="#{false}" the HTML isn't sent to the client at all. Only when the boolean expression is set to true and either the page reloaded or the enclosing component re-rendered via ajax will this content be sent to the client browser.